# Nagios nrpe command not defined....but it is

Tags: postgresql, nagios, nrpe

I'm using nagios and npre to monitor 2 different postgres databases.
I have series of commands in `nrpe.cfg` that work but when I use this particular one it says `command "check_X_COMMAND not defined"`.

I use the command twice in the nrpe, once for each DB I want to check:

```
command[check_postgres_check_lock_db1]=/etc/nagios/check_postgres_locks --dbname=DB1
command[check_postgres_check_lock_db2]=/etc/nagios/check_postgres_locks --dbname=DB2
```

DB1 is the on that is returning that error.
I can run the command from the nrpe client without any issue.

My services and commands are defined properly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the exact error code. Which command is undefined check_nrpe or check_postgres_check_lock_db1? I guess the first one.

If the command really works on nrpe client (so nagios server) with 
`/path_to_nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H server -t 30 -c check_postgres_check_lock_db1`

You have to define check_nrpe in `/path_to_nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg`

```
define command{
        command_name check_nrpe
        command_line $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -t 30 -c $ARG1$
}
```

then you can use it in a server.cfg

```
define service {
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       server
        service_description             db
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_postgres_check_lock_db1
}
```